# PHP Database Query: How to return the results from a while loop to a Javascript Variable?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, conditional-statements

I have a php query like so:

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $usertable . " ORDER BY fname;";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<option value="' . $row['pkid'] . '">' . $row['fname'] . ' ' . $row['lname'] . '</option>';
    }
?>
```

Within this same .php file I have some javascript. All I would like to do is return `$row['fname']` as a a javascript variable.

Is this possible?

Comment: **Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).** They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). **Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)** instead, and **use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo).**

Comment: Just a codebase took over, but I will look into prepared statements and PDO, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to output the PHP variable in a JavaScript variable you could do something like this -

```
echo '<script>var name+' . $row['pkid'] . ' = ' .$row['fname'] . ';</script>';
```

This would give you a uniquely named variable for each row.